# Подстановка переменной в запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

здесь переменные

```
var deviceTypes_2832 = false;
var device_Types;
```

Условие

```
if (deviceTypes_2832 == false) {
    device_Types = 2832;

}  if (deviceTypes_2832 == true) {  
    device_Types = '';
}
```

Есть аякс запрос. в который необходимо при загрузке страницы чтобы корректно проставлялась переменная со значением `device_Types = 2832;`

```
function (getCheck) {

  deviceTypes_2832 == false;

$.ajax({
        url: window.antraksHost + device_Types, 
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        success:function (result) {

        },
        error:function (result) {
            console.error( 'GET /devices' );
        }
    });
   }

getCheck();
```

При клике по кнопке чекбокса необходимо что в аякс подставлялась

```
device_Types = '';



// Клик по кнопке добавления чекбокса
$('#toggles').click(function() {

   if (deviceTypes_2832 == true) {  

    getCheck();
   } 


});
```

Comment: В чём конкретно ваш вопрос? / Что не работает?

Comment: В функции `getCheck`  фигурируем `deviceTypes_2832 == false;` - это вы хотели проверить значение или может быть присвоить?

Comment: При загрузке страницы (по умолчанию) в переменную в аякс подставляется device_Types = 2832,  нужно чтобы при клике по чекбоксу (стоит чек "on") отправлялся запрос с этой переменной =" " (т.е.пусто).. при клике по чекбоксу "off"  в переменную опять значение device_Types = 2832  , как то так ..